# Using the definition of the limit of a sequence show that zero is not a limit of $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Using the definition of the limit of a sequence show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}\neq0.$$

I know I should show that we cannot find $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0$ we
have

$$\left|\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}\right|<\epsilon,$$

but I do not know how to do this. I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{n^2 - 1}{n^2 + 1} = 1 - \frac 2{n^2 + 1}
\end{equation*}
Can you use this to show that $(n^2 - 1)/(n^2 + 1) > k$ for all $n > n_0$ for some $n_0$ and $k > 0$? This means that this value of $k$ is a counterexample to the requirement for the limit to be $0$.

Comment: This will be always > 0, but k should be greater than 0, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "for some $k > 0$". You could try seeing if there's a positive lower bound when $n \ge 2$, for example.

Comment: For $n=2$ we have $a_n = \frac{1}{3}$, so lower bound can be for example $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @Uhans You've got the right idea! Once you have such a lower bound the sequence cannot possibly converge to $0$, since the requirement is "for all $\varepsilon > 0$", so then the lower bound is a counterexample. However I think you forgot to square $n$ `:)`. Also be careful to use the alternative way of writing the $n$th term to *prove* the sequence remains strictly greater than your lower bound

Comment: Thank you. So, this answer is: I can find some $n_0$ such that for all n greater than $n_0$ we have $|a_n-0|>k$ (for example $n_0=2$ and $k=2/5$).

Answer (score 1):

If the equality is possible, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $$n^{2}-1 < \varepsilon(n^{2}+1)$$
for sufficiently large $n$, and hence $$n^{2} < \frac{1+\varepsilon}{1 - \varepsilon}$$
for sufficiently large $n$; 
so, taking $\varepsilon := 1/2$, for example, the possibility is a lie.